# Redirecting to laravel view after a download

Tags: php, laravel-5

How do I redirect to another page for successfully exporting a laravel view file. I am using Laravel Excel 2.1.20. 
I researched and I discovered that this can't be done except I redirect first and then download the excel sheet. I did the below but still does not work.

**Here is my controller:**

```
$export = Excel::create('Request for Quote', function($excel) use($item, $request) {
    $excel->sheet('RFQ 1', function($sheet) use($item, $request) {
    $sheet->loadView('requests.send_rfq_pdf')
        ->with('item', $item)
        ->with('request', $request);
    });
});
session(['download.in.the.next.request' => $export]);
return back();
```

**My View:**

```
@if(Session::has('download.in.the.next.request'))
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url={{Session::get('download.in.the.next.request') }}">
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If you trigger the download of the Excel file via a `POST` request, using a closure like `->download("xlsx");`, your browser will not have to redirect anywhere.

For example:

```
// ExampleController.php
public function postDownload(Request $request){
  Excel::create('Request for Quote', function($excel) use($item, $request) {
    $excel->sheet('RFQ 1', function($sheet) use($item, $request) {
      $sheet->loadView('requests.send_rfq_pdf')
      ->with('item', $item)
      ->with('request', $request);
    });
  })->download("xlsx");
}
```

You would need a `route` to handle this post request:

```
// routes.php:
Route::post("/pdf/download", "ExampleController@postDownload");
```

and a `view` with a simple form to generate a `POST` request to the route defined if your `routes.php` file:

```
<!-- {view}.blade.php -->
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/pdf/download') }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}/>
  <button type="submit">Download</button>
</form>
```